# Greedy Algorithm: Assigning jobs to minimize cost

Tags: algorithm

What is the best approach to take if I want to find the minimum total cost if I want to assign n jobs to a person in a sequence which have cost assigned to them? For eg. I have 2 jobs which have costs 4 and 5 respectively. Both jobs take 6 and 10 minutes respectively. So the finish time of the second job will be finish time of first job + time taken by this job. So the total cost will be finish time of each job multiplied by its cost.

Comment: sound like using recursive will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to assign n jobs to 1 person (or 1 machine) in scheduling literature terminology, you are looking to minimize weighted flow time. The problem is polynomially solvable.

The shortest weighted processing time sequence is optimal.

Sort and reindex jobs such that p_1/w_1 <= p_2/w_2 <= ... <= p_n/w_n,

where, p_i is the processing time of the ith job and w_i is its weight or cost.

Then, assign job 1 first, followed by 2 and so on until n.

Comment: 2431, cost = 62. 2413, cost = 65.

Comment: Sorry, I think yours is opt.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at what happens if you swap two adjacent values you will end up comparing terms like (A+c)m + (A+c+d)l and (A+d)l + (A+c+d)m, where A is the time consumed by earlier jobs, c and d are times, and l and m are costs. With some algebra and rearrangement you can see that the first version is smaller if c/m < d/l. So you could work out for each job the time taken by that job divided by its cost, and do first the jobs with smallest time per unit cost. - check: if you have a job that takes 10 years and has a cost of 1 cent, you want to do that last so that 10 year wait doesn't get multiplied by any other costs.